# Showing hidden directories in Project Explorer view

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

My Eclipse RCP application includes the Project Explorer view, which by default hides all directories whose name starts with the dot (".") character.

Is it possible to customize the Project Explorer view so that these directories are no longer hidden?

EDIT: I would like to do this programmatically.

Comment: This can be configured in the 'Customize View...' dialog in the Project Explorer view menu.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. My goal was to do this programmatically, and I ended up looking at the code behind the Customize View dialog for inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this by looking at the code behind the Customize View dialog (accessing the dialog is described [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-48b.htm)).

The `INavigatorFilterService` interface provides the `activateFilterIdsAndUpdateViewer` method, which allows callers to activate certain filters and deactivate all others. The `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources` plugin defines the `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.filters.startsWithDot` filter, which is used to remove all files and directories whose name starts with a dot character from the Project Explorer view.

The following code snippet can be used:

```
      ProjectExplorer projectExpl = ... // get project explorer
      INavigatorContentService contentServ = projectExpl.getNavigatorContentService();
      INavigatorFilterService filterServ = contentServ.getFilterService();
      String[] enabledFilters = new String[0]; // this will clear all filters
      filterServ.activateFilterIdsAndUpdateViewer(enabledFilters);
```